# Визуальные редакторы JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, какие есть визуальные редакторы для яваскрипт? Или их может просто нет!

Comment: визуальный редактор для Языка программирования? думаю его нет

Comment: Если именно визуальный - для какого-то Google языка есть такой... Ну и ДРАКОН )))

Comment: тогда и черепашка :) все же даже в черепашке нужно писать код чтоб передвигалась она. а визуальный редактор для Яп это ты мышкой сначала растягиваешь область для класса и перетягиваешь туда функции :D

Comment: Я про это и говорю...

Comment: где скачать этот "Дракон"

Answer (score 2):

Если речь про IDE, то

- Visual Studio + Web Developer Express,
- WebStorm,
- любой блокнот по Windows или Unix + отладочная панель браузера,
- ...

Если речь про форму ввода, то

- TinyMCE,
- CKEditor,
- WMD,
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно [это](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors) - то что вы хотели